# How do I create a reusable JavaScript component

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a JavaScript component that is reusable in any web application (pure js only allowed). And more than one instance can exist at a time on a web page.

**Client HTML**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="MyComponent.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            MyComponent.init();
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
var MyComponent = {};

(function () {
    var ns = MyComponent;
    ns.init = function () { alert('test'); }
}());
```

How would I instantiate the component above?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Is something in your code not working? What do you expect to be `new`ing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the gist of it:

```
function MyComponent() {
  //constructor
}

MyComponent.prototype.doStuff = function() {
  //method
}

MyComponent.doSomething = function() {
  //static method
}
```

And heres how you'd use it

```
var component = new MyComponent();
component.doStuff();

MyComponent.doSomething();
```

Comment: I think `function MyComponent() {...}` would be more standard.

Comment: Completely! Don't know why I wrote it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the **constructor pattern**. See explanations and the Car example [on this page](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript).

Excerpt from the article:

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.miles = miles;
  this.toString = function () {
    return this.model + " has done " + this.miles + " miles";
  };
}
// Usage:
// We can create new instances of the car
var civic = new Car( "Honda Civic", 2009, 20000 );
var mondeo = new Car( "Ford Mondeo", 2010, 5000 );
```